# I had dual boot with windows and linux (fedora), but I can't use it anymore

Tags: linux, windows-10, multi-boot, shutdown

In order to use linux (Fedora 26) and not have to loose windows 10 I installed Fedora with dual boot.

My computer randomly turned off (it completely turned off, it did not even show the shutdown screen, it simply powered off). I still do not understand why since I was doing nothing, I had 50% battery and there was no part of the computer that was hot at all. After I managed to turn it on it immediately opened windows, it did not even show the option to choose. The partition still exists, so I do not think linux was eliminated.

What could it be and how do I put it back?

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean it turned off once, or on a regular basis? When installing Windows AFTER Linux, Windows inserts its own bootloader. That breaks the dual boot. Maybe (I am not a specialist) an update made Windows updating what it thought was its bootloader?

Anyway you can try booting from a Linux live USB stick to reinstall grub2. Assuming your HDD is `/dev/sda` and your linux partition `/dev/sda1` (check with `fdisk`):

```
# mount -t ext4 /dev/sda1 /mnt
# mount --bind /dev /mnt/dev
# mount --bind /sys /mnt/sys
# mount --bind /proc /mnt/proc
# chroot /mnt
# grub-install
```

Comment: No I installed linux in a computer that has window. It suddently the screen went black and it was off. Basically I can not initiate linux. I will try to reinstall it.

Comment: You can try as I suggested before reinstalling: boot any flavour of Linux from a USB stick and try to repair the bootloader.